# Generating Heatmaps from coordinates, what is my error can't seem to iterate over rows

Tags: python, data-science

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import matplotlib as mpl

# Read original image
img = io.imread('tokyo_snapshot.png')
x_dim, y_dim, z_dim = np.shape(img)
heatmap = np.zeros((x_dim, y_dim), dtype=float)

df = pd.read_csv("sheet1.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
 x = np.int(row["x"])
 y = np.int(row["y"])
 x1 = np.int(row["x1"])
 y1 = np.int(row["y1"])
 p = row["Probability value"]
 heatmap[x:x1,y:y1] = p
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyang\OneDrive\Desktop\Penis\penis.py", line 17, in <module>
    x = np.int(row["x"])
  File "C:\Users\kyang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__        
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\kyang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4419, in get_value   
    raise e1
  File "C:\Users\kyang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value   
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x'
```

Above is my code, im trying to iterate over rows, however, I keep receiving the error that is in the picture, does anyone know the fix to this problem?

Comment: Kindly include the traceback in the post only, not as a separate picture.

Comment: what's the content of row?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `KeyError: 'x'` which means that `column x` does not exist in this row.
Make sure that you are reading the csv correctly (You can print the first 5 rows by `print(df.head())` or print the columns names as `print(df.columns)`)